# Populating a departure date field which is after the arrival date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Step 1

Arrival Date (Already generated) – 1.35 Million Times

Step 2

Randomise a number between 0 and 1

Step 3

Use the Randomised number produced above to create the script below

```
UPDATE BOOKINGS
SET DepartureDate
CASE WHEN RAND() Result = Between 0 and 0.3 = Departure Date will be 2 Nights Later 
CASE WHEN RAND() Result = Between 0.3 and 0.4 = Departure Date will be 3 Nights Later
CASE WHEN RAND ()Result >0.4 = Departure Date will be either 1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28 Nights Later
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use RAND() with a changing seed. It makes for terribly randomized data.

To get to your solution you need to create "buckets" of possible values. 3 days is supposed to happen in 10% of the cases; that makes the smallest bucket, so we need ten buckets. 2 days goes into 3 buckets. The other values go into 2 buckets each. then just use modulo to select one of the 10 buckets like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.booking(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,days INT);

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.booking(days)
SELECT TOP(100000) 0 FROM sys.columns A,sys.columns B,sys.columns C,sys.columns D;

GO


UPDATE b
 SET days = rndm.days
FROM dbo.booking b
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT days
   FROM (VALUES(0,2),(1,2),(2,2),(3,3),(4,1),(5,1),(6,4),(7,4),(8,28),(9,28))dn(n,days)
   WHERE n = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID(),b.Id))%10
)rndm;

GO

SELECT days,COUNT(1) cnt
FROM dbo.booking
GROUP BY days;


GO
```

EDIT: Updated code to not use case statement.

Comment: Hi Sebastian

I have 1.35 million arrival dates and each one of these needs to have a departure date, when I run your query above I have nulls in the departure date and also missing stays for example I have no 4 night stays or 9 night stays.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I updated the code to not use the case statement, as that was messing things up. As for the 9 nights, that is not part of your requirement listed above, so it not showing up is expected.

Comment: Hi Sebastian

I have rewritten my requirement (See Above) because I don't think I have explained it correctly (I am really new to SQL).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know the final solution I used was:

```
UPDATE BOOKINGS 
SET DepartureDate = 
DATEADD(day, 
CASE WHEN Rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) BETWEEN 0 and 0.3 THEN 2 ELSE 
CASE WHEN Rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) BETWEEN 0.3 and 0.5 THEN 3 ELSE 
Round(Rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 28,0) END END,ArrivalDate)
```

Thanks

Wayne